# Google Tag Manager - Capture Select Values

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am attempting to capture `<select>` values, push them to the Data Layer and push them to an Analytics account using Google Tag Manager. Here's the code I'm trying to scrape values from **which contains a dynamic selected attribute**:

```
<select class="dropdown__select" size="1" id="dyeMethod" name="dyeMethod" onchange="javascript:UpdateSearchResults('FilterSearchForm')">
                                        <option value="ALL">ALL</option>

        <option value="395" >
         Piece Dyed</option>            

        <option value="402"  selected="selected">
         Solution Dyed</option>            

        <option value="406" >
         Solution Dyed /  Yarn Dyed</option>            

                            </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

First, I created a custom HTML tag to grab the proscribed values and push them to the Data Layer (tag code below):

```
    document.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      if (e.target.className === 'dropdown__select') {
        var selected = e.target.options ? e.target.options[e.target.value] : undefined;

        window.dataLayer.push({
          'event' : 'valueSelected',
          'selectedValue' : selected ? (selected.value) : ''
        });
      }
    };
```

This tag fires on DOM Ready and when 'valueSelected' is pushed to the data layer. I then created a Data Layer Variable ('selectedValue') and assigned it as the Event Label on a GA tag that fires only when the 'dropdown__select' class is selected.

The tags pass the category and and action along, but the label displays as '(not set)'. There must be a more efficient way to capture these values and pass them along!!

Comment: Try to do the evaluation of the value for "selectedValue" before the dataLayer push.

Comment: @nyuen I just updated the code above to show that I am also wanting to capture only the value which is dynamically selected. I apologize for not using this example earlier, since it pushes all of the values in the select menu, instead of just the one selected. Thanks for all your help so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM Ready and valueSelected are both values of event key so there is no way to fire custom HTML tag using both this rules in one trigger.

Try to fire custom HTML tag on DOM Ready and Google Analytics tag on event equals valueSelected.